# Extension of Fuch's theorem using Jonathan Pila's argument

Tags: cv.complex-variables

There is an extension to Carlson's theorem due to Fuch's that goes as follows:
If $f$ is an entire holomorphic function such that 
$$|f(z)| < C e^{\frac{\pi}{2}|z|}$$
then if $f(2k)=0$ for all $k=0,1,\ldots$ it follows that $f(z) \equiv 0$ on $\mathbb C$.

At the same time there is an extension to the classical Carlson's theorem for entire functions vanishing on integers, that roughly allows faster growth along real axis by sacrificing growth on imaginary axis. The precise statement can be found here
http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/pila/carlson.pdf

Is it possible to combine these two statements that derives a similar result like the one by Pila, but for functions vanishing on even integers?